# How do I Send Keys in a Game?

Tags: knight-online

Basically I would like to "press" two keys continuously (q and 3 over and over again) in a game through vbs. I made a vbs file which I tested in notepad and it worked, but as I run it, and click on the game it does nothing. However, if I run it, click on the game, and press enter, which opens the chatbox in the game, then I can see it's typing q3q3q3. Actually you select the nearest target with Q and shoot and arrow with 3  - Just so you can get a better idea of what I would like to accomplish exactly. Thank you in advance - Alex (the game is NOT minecraft)

Comment: Are you asking about scripting actions in a game? It would help to mention which game... Many prevent what you're trying to do (write a bot, by the sounds of it) since it's basically cheating. The impact varies by game, but still.

Comment: The game is called Knight Online. And uhm... yeah.. I guess it's cheating, but obviously harmless to other players

Answer (score 0):

hey sounds like you have a Rogue in K.O.

so cause thats an old game you should look for some already existing scripts. There are basicly for every class some, most famous are the Healer "bots" but the auto grinder for Rogue should also be easy to find in google.
But if you realy whant to "programm" a vbs skript your self consider asking in the stackOverflow section of stackexchange where its about programming and not "gaming".